# Copying data from S3 to Redshift hangs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I've been trying to load data into `Redshift` for the last couple of days with no success. I have provided the correct `IAM` role to the cluster, I have given access to `S3`, I am using the `COPY` command with either the `AWS` credentials or the `IAM` role and so far no success. What can be the reason for this? It has come to the point that I don't have many options left.

So the code is pretty basic, nothing fancy there. See below:

```
copy test_schema.test from 's3://company.test/tmp/append.csv.gz' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<rolenumber>/RedshiftCopyUnload'
delimiter ',' gzip;
```

I didn't put any error messages because there are none. The code simply hangs and I have left it running for well over 40 minutes with no results. If I go into the Queries section in Redshift I dont see any abnormal. I am using Aginity and SQL Workbench to run the queries.

I also tried to manually insert queries in Redshift and seems that works. COPY and UNLOAD do not work and even though I have created Roles with access to S3 and associated with the cluster I still get this problem.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Solution has been found. Basically it was a connectivity problem within our VPC. A VPC endpoint had to be created and associated with the subnet used by Redshift.

Comment: To be able to assist you, we will need more information. Please edit your question to include a sample of the input data, the `COPY` command you are using, the error message you are receiving, plus any other information that would help us to try and diagnose/reproduce your situation.

Comment: As well as the above, if you can log on to the aws console, check the resource usage of redshift (io and cpu) and also check the load job on there (is it in "running" state).  If you have the ddl (including sort / dist ) of the target table and the know sort order of your input data. Lastly, the number of rows & size of your cluster.

Comment: For future reference, I ran into a similar problem which ended up being two things. First, when setting up a Gateway Endpoint in your VPC for connecting to S3, make sure that the gateway is applied to the subnets that your redshift cluster is actually using. Additionally, make sure that your redshift security group set for the database has proper outbound rules.

Comment: For anyone else that might have this issue, try what @yuval-itzchakov suggested, add an outbound rules to the security group.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JohnRotenstein that, there needs more information to provide the answer. I would suggest you to take simple data points and simple table.
Here are step-by-step solution, I hope by doing that, you should be able to resolve your issue.

Assume here is your table structure.

Here I'm  doing most of  data types to prove my point.
    create table sales(
    salesid integer,
    commission decimal(8,2),
    saledate date,
    description varchar(255),
    created_at timestamp default sysdate,
    updated_at timestamp);

Just to make it simple, here is your data file resides in S3.
Content in CSV(sales-example.txt)

```
salesid,commission,saledate,description,created_at,updated_at
1|3.55|2018-12-10|Test description|2018-05-17 23:54:51|2018-05-17 23:54:51
2|6.55|2018-01-01|Test description|2018-05-17 23:54:51|2018-05-17 23:54:51
4|7.55|2018-02-10|Test description|2018-05-17 23:54:51|2018-05-17 23:54:51
5|3.55||Test description|2018-05-17 23:54:51|2018-05-17 23:54:51
7|3.50|2018-10-10|Test description|2018-05-17 23:54:51|2018-05-17 23:54:51
```

Run following two command using the psql terminal or any sql connector. Make sure to run second command as well.

```
copy sales(salesid,commission,saledate,description,created_at,updated_at) from 's3://example-bucket/foo/bar/sales-example.txt' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=************;aws_secret_access_key=***********' IGNOREHEADER  1;

commit;
```

I hope, this should help you in debugging your issue.

Comment: Thanks but that didnt work either. I run it and what I can see in Redshift Queries is `COPY ANALYZE sales` and my SQL client tools hanging.

Comment: Does your select query runs fine, select * from tab1, if so, insert few record manually and then try unload command to same bucket? This should tell you if there is connection issue.

Comment: So I tried everything and I think there is a connectivity issue between Redshift and S3. INSERT queries work perfectly fine. UNLOAD and COPY don't work. I run this through our VPC and I have setup a Role with Read only access to S3 but not sure what is the issue. The Role is associated with the cluster, all looks good but no COPY

Comment: Was your redshift in private subnet or same issue with Public accessible true ?