# Redshift COPY command takes forever

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have created a brand new Redshift cluster with Terraform. I am able to connect to it and run COPY command but even for small CSV files with 10 lines it takes forever. I have rebooted cluster but is the same. Also there are no errors in `stl_load_errors` table.
Did someone experience similar issue?

Comment: Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403088/copying-data-from-s3-to-redshift-hangs

Comment: It seems very general. Could you please share the code you are using (with dummy values) ?

Comment: I have added answer @Earnest

Answer (score 0):

Here is Terraform code for creating VPC endpoint. Maybe at some point I will create complete template for Redshift and update this post.

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3_vpc_endpoint" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.region}.s3"
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" "s3_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" {
  route_table_id  = aws_route_table.route_table.id
  vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3_vpc_endpoint.id
}
```